# Can I push objects into Vue component data? Wanting to make a table after js filtering/manipulation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to make a table. Actually, I am making a website with many pages with many tables, so I wanted to make a table component. The table data has not yet been put into the table because I need to manipulate the data a lot in js.

When js is done with it, I intended to push every row object into the data property of my Vue Component (to then do a v-for in the html to fill the table).

but I cant find anyone pushing data into vue components. Are the examples right under my nose?

if I don't push into components themselves, that means I need to push into the parent vm? which means a new data property per table instance ..?

I am really struggling putting together the bigger picture connection when it comes to connecting Vue with the outputs from js... Looking for any input

Comment: If you pass an array as a Vue prop and then push additional elements onto the array, the component updates as expected. There are some [caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats), but those don't apply if you use `Array.prototype.push()`

Answer (score 0):

Pushing data into a vue component is not a good practice. You would have a lot easier time if you use Vuex for what you're trying to do. Then you could build a closed-loop data system that updates state data in Vuex with mutations and returns the update to component with a getter. Doing all of this within component is possible if you initialize your data property correctly, though.

To actually answer your question, though, you would do it like this:

```
 data () {
       return {
          myData: [],
          someDataObject: null
       }
    }
...
methods: {
   fillData () {
      this.myData.push(this.someDataObject);
   }
}
```

And in template:

```
...
<div v-for(item in myData, index) :key:item item:item>
   <input type:'text' v-model="someDataObject">
   <button @click="fillData();"></button>
   <p>{{myData[0]}}</p>
</div>
...
```